# How do I iterate over SqlDelight select results without loading everything into memory?

Tags: android, kotlin, sqldelight

As far as I can see [SqlDelight Query object](https://cashapp.github.io/sqldelight/2.0.0/2.x/runtime/app.cash.sqldelight/-query/index.html) doesn't have any way to query items one by one instead of everything as a whole like [executeAsList()](https://cashapp.github.io/sqldelight/2.0.0/2.x/runtime/app.cash.sqldelight/-executable-query/execute-as-list.html). I have a large table to process and I can't load everything into memory.

The [execute()](https://cashapp.github.io/sqldelight/2.0.0/2.x/runtime/app.cash.sqldelight/-executable-query/execute.html) function comes in close, since that allows me to run each result through a mapper, but you lose type safety and are back to raw sqlite columns and casting:

```kotlin
val a = mDb.testQueries.selectAll().execute { cursor ->
    while (cursor.next().value) {
        println("cursor $cursor")
    }
    QueryResult.Unit
}
```

Another alternative is passing the mapper as the constructor to the query, so you regain the type safety. Unfortunately this has to return the whole result, so it is wasting memory returning a list as long as the whole table.

```kotlin
mDb.testQueries.selectAll { id, foo, bar, timestamp ->
    println("Running on id $id, timestamp $timestamp")
}.executeAsList()
```

Is there really no way to query a big table other than writing my own pagination code?

**UPDATE**: Extension function based on [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76926510/172690):

```kotlin
    fun <RowType : Any> Query<RowType>.iterate(block: (RowType) -> Unit) {
        execute { cursor ->
            while (cursor.next().value) {
                block(mapper(cursor))
            }
            QueryResult.Unit
        }
    }
    …
    mDb.testQueries.selectAll().iterate { id, foo, bar, timestamp ->
        …
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mapper` which is part of `ExecutableQuery`, same as [`executeAsList`](https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight/blob/6e2ee5bb358babb40a86759c1def3b2d18e505bc/runtime/src/commonMain/kotlin/app/cash/sqldelight/Query.kt#L174) does:

```
val query = mDb.testQueries.selectAll()
query.execute { cursor ->
    while (cursor.next().value) {
        val typeSafeValue = query.mapper(cursor)
        // process and release
    }
    QueryResult.Unit
}
```